# catalin.jar not found in apache tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate

I used Apache tomcat 7 so hibernate part this error come. How to solve.[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DEog.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an error.  It is just telling you that you haven't told Eclipse where to find the Tomcat source code.

Solution:

1. Download the Tomcat source code bundle.
2. Click the "Attach source..." button, and tell Eclipse where you put the source code.

Comment: I downloaded tomcat source and attached nut this massage came

Comment: Did you download the complete source bundle?  The correct version?  Did you attach it correctly?  Hint: Eclipse expects either a directory tree or a ZIP or JAR containing the sources.  (Not a TAR file consisting of all sorts of stuff .... that you need to untar first.)